# nonenghlish chars on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, console

After I do this 
wget http://www.francefootball.fr/

All the french accents are displayed wrong on the console.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an compatible encoding to correctly show the foreign chars. Use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` to select the locales for your machine. Set it to a UTF-8 locale and see if it fixes.

Comment: It is already UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Which console are you using? If you're connecting using PuTTY you need to change the character encoding under the settings. I'm not on a Windows machine at the moment so I can't guide you through each step but I think it's under Session -> Encoding or similar.

Answer (score 0):

When my term gets messed up, I run reset, and that fixes it:

```
reset
```